# Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to prevent this error, I am trying what ever I can, not possible to add return inside map.

Error:
Line 32:26:  Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function  array-callback-return

```
  const parseChartData = (field: string, data: string[][]) => {
    let chartData = [[field, 'count']];
    data.map((item: any) => {
      chartData.push([item._id, item._count])
    });
    return chartData;
  };
```

Comment: The map function requires a return. if you don't want to map a new array then use forEach. That will go through every item in the array. so do: data.forEach((.....

Comment: or just `for (const item of data) { }`, which is usually faster

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to convert your `data` into pairs of `[id, count]`, prepended by a header pair `[field, 'count']`?

Leaving type aside, you could:

1. Convert `data` into `chartData` with `map`
2. Prepend the header with `array.unshift()`

```
const chartData = data.map((item) => 
  [item._id, item._count]
);
chartData.unshift([field, 'count']);
```

---

As for types, make sure your parameter typing is consistent with how you use it:

- `data` parameter is declared as `string[][]`
- each of its items (hence a `string[]`) is used as `item._id, item._count`, i.e. we try accessing its `_id` and `_count` properties, which are not supposed to exist on `string[]`

Hence the very probable reason why you had to type each `item` as `any`.

If your `data` is actually an array of objects with `_id` and `_count` properties, then simply type it ad such:

```
data: Array<{ _id: string; _count: number }>
```

Comment: I want to fix the eslint error, btw thanks for your explanation, it does help me to understand better.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you expect? Do you mean you just want to silence the eslint message? Why do you say you cannot add a `return`? And why do you want to stick with `map` instead of `forEach` or an equivalent?

Comment: Ya i stick with foreach for now, because I can't add  a return inside that map to silence that eslint error.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to map return data，Why not use forEach？please look up mdn docs

```
const parseChartData = (field: string, data: string[][]) => {
    let chartData = [[field, 'count']];
    data.forEach((item: any) => {
      chartData.push([item._id, item._count])
    });
    return chartData;
  };
```

Comment: Ya forEach solve the problem, but I was trying to figure how to solve with map.

Comment: i thinks the design of map there will be no such scene，for me, map are used for pure functions.  if you want to do，try add eslint rule （array-callback-return：0） ？